# Is there any way to run wso2am-analytics with yajsw-stable-12.14?

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager, mssql-jdbc, yajsw

I am using wso2am-3.2.0 and then yajsw-stable-12.14 to use it as a windows service. But this error appears when I want to install wso2am-analytics with MSSQL DB. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does the same error happens when you run the same in the CMD terminal via command line. You could get error logs on the terminal and probably the error log would indicate what to be rectified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, the issue was that I had used the wrong Database. If The database that we used for analytics is different from that contained roles and users, this error will appear.